# OSX zsh not showing characters right (with UTF8)

Tags: macos, zsh, locale

After setting the locale to 'en_US.utf8', all the characters(except a-z A-Z) are not showing correctly. For example, space will show up as '<0020>'

The locale is:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

And if the locale is not set, the characters are shown correctly.

```
LC_LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C"
...
```

Also, bash won't have this problem.

Comment: I set my locale with `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8  
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and it works ok still for me. Problem probably lies elsewhere.. Are u using iterm?

Comment: @KarthikT yes, I use iterm2, and this problem also occurs on terminal.

Comment: Even works for me on system `zsh` v 4.3.11.. Not sure.

Comment: Please check if your zsh is compiled with multibyte support. Using a clean shell (`zsh -f`) issue `[[ -o multibyte ]] && echo on` and check if it prints _on_.

Comment: @mpy Really sorry for late reply, the result on my local machine shows "on", any ideas?